# jQuery function to hide/show rows depending on cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have the following table layout:

```
Company_Name | Address | Date
------------------------------
Company A     address1   date 
Company A     address1   diff-date
Company A     address1   diff-date
```

Is there a way to make the bottom two rows hidden and when clicking the first 'Company A' row should reveal those two rows? Basically I want any of the same values of Company Name to be hidden as a sub row of the first instance of a company.

Edit: current code:

```
<table id="companyTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Company_Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>CompanyA</td>
        <td>Address1</td>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>CompanyA</td>
        <td>Address1</td>
        <td>Diff-Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>CompanyA</td>
        <td>Address1</td>
        <td>Diff-Date</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show your source HTML? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far as I don't know how to do it

Comment: @Dave You have to show that you tried... We won't supply code for you...

Comment: TBH, [this is a good place to start](http://docs.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tr class="company_a">
  ...
</tr>
<tr class="company_a">
  ...
</tr>
<tr class="company_a">
  ...
</tr>
<script>

// hide all company_a
$(".company_a").hide();

// show first company_a
$(".company_a:first").show().click(function() {

  // show all company_a when first company_a is clicked
  $(".company_a").show();

});
</script>
```